# Same lengtht for a group of values in a column of a Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to get the same lengtht for a group of values (0,1,2,3,4,5) in a column of a Data Frame. For example, I would like to reduce the amount of every group of values to the lowest exisiting (= 41)

input: `train_df.relevancy.value_counts()`

output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9JWr.png)

Comment: Please provide a minimal and reproducible example, cf https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC use [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) by minimal value from [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
val = train_df.relevancy.value_counts().min()
train_df = train_df.groupby('relevancy').head(val)
```